# Hibernate 5.0.3 persistence works fine in a standalone project but fails in EAR on Glassfish 4.1 deploy

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, glassfish

I have a Maven enterprise project that is composed of ear, web and ejb modules. The EJB module uses JPA persistence with Hibernate 5.0.3 as a provider. I have a bunch of JPQL queries that use “SELECT NEW com.package.path.CustomerReport(anotherEntityObject, COUNT(anotherEntityObject.repList))....” type of syntax. When  I test these queries outside the Glassfish, they work just fine. However, when I deploy the project as part of the ear to a Glassfish 4.1 app server, the deployment process fails. Hibernate complains that it cannot not find a matching constructor (“ERROR: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class... Expected arguments are:...”). The constructor is there; and the order of arguments is correct. After all it works with no issues outside the app server.

One of the threads below suggest to put @SuppressWarning(“unchecked”) when working with these types of queries (SELECT NEW...). This has been already placed in the code by prior developer. When using EclipseLink I do not have this issue. I would think that this would work with Hibernate as I am using standard JPA. Somebody must have had a similar problem. What could be a cause of this error? Could there be an issue in the way the project gets built by Maven(maybe @SuppressWarning is not included)? I would appreciate if anyone could provide a suggestion or a fix for the problem.

Thank you very much.

Things I have considered/looked at:

- [JPQL/Hibernate limitation using constructor expression in SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821074/jpql-hibernate-limitation-using-constructor-expression-in-select)
- [JPA JPQL: SELECT NEW with COUNT, GROUP BY and ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477734/jpa-jpql-select-new-with-count-group-by-and-order-by)
- [hibernate: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class - HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224093/hibernate-unable-to-locate-appropriate-constructor-on-class-hql)

Comment: I'd suggest you analyse the full error message - what arguments' types are expected? It seems to me the two ORM you're using are mapping database types to Java types in distinct ways.

Comment: Caffe, thank you for your suggestion. I thought the same thing at first as the error message went something like this: `ERROR:    Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.package.path.CustomerReport]. Expected arguments are: com.package.path.AnotherEntityObject, long
[cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: com.package.path.CustomerReport]` The constructor for the CustomerReport had the second argument type Long (wrapper class). I've changed it to a primitive long even-though hibernate documentation says _COUNT ... is always Long._

Comment: I still get the same error no matter whether I use long or Long. Here is Hibernate doc: [Section 13.4.7. Aggregate functions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/)

Comment: Can you check if the Glassfish already provides Hibernate, may be it is a version mismatch of the hibernate?

Comment: I double-checked  _modules_ folder. Hibernate is not there. Glassfish 4.1 comes with EclipseLink 2.1.6 as its default JPA.

Comment: I down-graded to 4.3.11 version of Hibernate. The project deploys but now I have another issue. The PU fails to load with NP exception: `Exception while dispatching an event
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus(JtaStatusHelper.java:76)...`